# Jaccard decay, Jaccard recall, and class-agnostic binary segmentation

Tags: computer-graphics

When reading about SiamMask (Wang et al., [Fast Online Object Tracking and Segmentation: A Unifying Approach](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.05050)), I encountered the terms "Jaccard decay" and "Jaccard recall".

I know what Jaccard index means, but not sure what is the meaning of Jaccard decay and Jaccard recall, and the difference between these terms.

Also, I don't understand what "class-agnostic binary segmentation for target object" means.

Comment: Where have you encountered these terms?

Comment: SiamMask VOT 2016 & 2018

Comment: Can you provide links?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.05050 section 4.2

Comment: And for class-agnostic segmentation is stated in abstract line 9

Comment: Your paper doesn't contain the terms "Jaccard decay" or "Jaccard recall".

Comment: Class-agnostic segmentation is mentioned in the context of reference [43]. Have you looked there?

Comment: I'm sorry is not VOT but DAVIS 2016 and it shows in table 4. So may I know the meaning of JM, JO, JD from the table? I'm confused

Comment: Immediately after this statement, there is a reference to [40]. Have you looked there?

Comment: I've read it and it stated region similarity (J) decay and recall. It's still confusing

Comment: I'm sorry for my limited english

Comment: These terms are defined in Section 6.1 of [40].

Comment: Thank you! I understand

Comment: Perhaps you can answer your own question now?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include all relevant information in the question.  Don't just leave stuff in the comments.  We want the question to be understandable for someone who encounters it for the first time.   Also, we ask that you research carefully and read all available resources *before* asking.  If you can answer your question by reading the paper you mention, or papers it cites, then you should do more research in the future before asking.